# Jpeg2000 with transparency

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, magick.net

I'm trying to use *Magick.Net* to convert a transparent Png to Jpeg2000 format and keep its transparency. The code is rather simple:

```cs
using(FileStream source = new FileStream(@"D:\test.png", FileMode.Open))
using(FileStream file = new FileStream(@"D:\test.jp2", FileMode.Create))
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(source))
{
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Jp2;
    image.Write(file);
}
```

The source image: [image] and result: [image]

As you can see, the image lost its transparency, while both images are 24BPP. What am I missing here?

Comment: Read following article : https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/transparency-with-jpegs-2f04faff028b

Comment: @jdweng The article is not about Jpeg2000 but about combining normal jpg with second image used as alpha bitmap mask. What should I find there regarding my problem?

Comment: It looks like from code that take a long time the transparent bits are the 8 MSB,  It looks like from code to make transparent the 2nd 8 MSBs are duplicated to the 8 MSBs.

Comment: I just tried your code with Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU (version 7.6.0) and the transparency was preserved. What version/build are you using?

Comment: @BradleySmith The same installed as a Nuget package. Have you used the same image or different?

Comment: @Romasz Same image. I opened the resulting JP2 file in Photoshop to confirm that the transparency was still present - it was.

Comment: @BradleySmith You are right, just checked with Photoshop also, I've used IrfanView and it doesn't show the transparency on Jpeg2000. Thanks for saving some time.